# Live synchronise from backup img to mounted partition

Tags: ubuntu

I want to sync backup to the currently running system. Just want to update all running files from my backup partition.

```
dd if=/tmp/backup.img of=/dev/sda bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible I think or I know of no way to update open files of which there should be a few on running system. Not to mention the /proc, /dev and all those files you will clobber doing it. How is the system supposed to continue running after that?